Buddy Algorithm free-function
I am trying to implement the function that frees a block in the buddy algorithm. Until now, I have the following code:
int buddy_free(struct block *block)
{
    switch (block->refcnt) {
    case 0:
        return -1; /* Double free */
    case 1:
        /*
         * TODO: what should happen here? Hint: use buddy_push. Hint:
         * also use __buddy_try_merge after you've implemented
         * __buddy_merge
         */
        block->refcnt = 0; 
        __buddy_try_merge(block); 

        return 0;
    default:
        /* TODO: and here? */
        int highest = __buddy_find_smallest_free_order(block->order)-1; 
        buddy_free(...); 
        buddy_free(...); 



        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
}

The block data structure is build as follows:
struct block {
    unsigned refcnt;
    unsigned order; /* 0 <= order <= BUDDY_MAX_ORDER */
    struct block *next;
};

where the refcnt field determines whether a block is free: if there is no one (i.e., no process or kernel) who holds a reference to this block, the block may be freed. Otherwise, upon a free, the block may not be freed, and we only decrease its reference count.
I don't really know how to continue, I think in the default case it should be implemented recursively.

Why would refcnt ever be more than 1? When you allocate the block it's set to 1, when you free the block it goes back to 0. Higher reference counts only occur in systems that use automatic memory management that increments the count every time another pointer to an object is created. It doesn't happen with manual malloc/free.
